# How to highlight the total row in Pivottable?

Tags: excel, vba

i would like to highlight the whole row of the Pivottable if in Pivotfield arise the value 0

my thought up to now was:

```
Sub ColorRows()

Dim r As Range
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot").PivotFields("Efüllungsgrad in %")

For Each r In .PivotItems
        Range(r, 3).Select
        Selection.Interior.ColorIndex = 6
Next r
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```

Thanks

Comment: [`PivotItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.pivotfield.pivotitems) is not a collection of `Range`s.

Comment: thanks but the logic fits? Means i have to find a way to assign my command to the wished column?

Comment: Why don't you use conditional formatting in your pivot?

Comment: You're looking for `PivotTables("TableName").DataBodyRange.Rows(i)`. Thats how you would iterate through pivot table rows. Your loop would look like `For i = 1 to PivotTables("TableName").DataBodyRange.Rows.Count`

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what you're asking, but if its a pivotfield that you want to highlight then you just need `PivotTables("TableName").PivotFields("FieldName").DataRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 6`

Comment: thanks, just to get it right...by TableName we mean the names manager in which i labeled the specific range right?  I do not want to highlight every single row, just the rows within the Fieldname which equal to 0

Comment: @EvR because i want to highlight the whole row not just the cell, or is that even possible in default mode?

Comment: @Sven Yes , a little different than normal conditional formatting but possible

Comment: @EvR im very interested for this idea. The only thing what i know is that conditional formating on total rows is just possible on plain tables but not on pivot tables and even on plaint tables you need to create a formular out of the table itself. Could you describe how you would do that? Thanks a lot.

Comment: see: https://www.contextures.com/excelpivottableconditionalformat.html

Comment: @EvR thanks. What i was looking for is to highlight a whole row if in cell(i,3) of the Pivot arise f.e the value 0. Within the documentation like i see its just about how to highlight within a Pivot Table a specific row...anyway of course helpful :)

Comment: Maybe you could add a pic of how your pivot must look like after the row colouring (add it to your question)

Answer (score 1):

I think I understand the question. You want to loop through the cells of one pivot field, and if you find a 0, you want to highlight the whole row.

```
Sub ColorRows()

    Dim pTable As PivotTable, pField As PivotField
    
    Set pTable = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Pivot")
    Set pField = pTable.PivotFields("Efüllungsgrad in %")
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    For i = 1 To pField.DataRange.Rows.Count
            If pField.DataRange.Cells(i, 1).Value = 0 Then
                pTable.DataBodyRange.Rows(i).Interior.ColorIndex = 6
            End If
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        
End Sub
```

I reference the table's range using `pTable.DataBodyRange`. I reference the PivotField's cells using `pField.DataRange`. And I link the two together by iterating with a counter rather than using an object for the loop.

Edit: This is also possible using conditional formatting, which is easier to implement and maintain.

Comment: first at all thanks! From the logic its what i want :) unfortunately the system gives me back an error because it can not assign the Pivot setting to the Active Worksheet. Do you know why?

Comment: Try changing `ActiveSheet` to `Sheets("Name")` where "Name" is the sheet that has your pivot table on it.

Comment: @Todleson that could solve the mistake but its still running on error -1004- Application or Object defined error. Can it be that we forgot to define "i"? And just to avoid a stupid error, i label the Pivot name by Pivot Option Label Name right?

Comment: If you step through it line by line, which line is giving you the object error?